# If $ M $ is an upper bound of $ A $ and $ \exists $ $ \{ a_n \} \in A :\lim \sup a_n = M $ prove that $ \sup A = M $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

I'm having some difficulty proving this proposition :

> Let $ A \subset \Bbb R $ with $ A \neq \emptyset $. If $ M $ is an upper bound of $ A $ and $ \exists $ $ \{ a_n \} \in A :\lim\limits \sup a_n = M $ show that $$ \sup A = M $$

Intuitively this proposition makes perfect sense to me but I have no idea how to prove it rigorously.

Comment: If $y$ is any number smaller than $M$, then you can find $n$ such that $a_n>y$ (why?) and so $y$ cannot be the supremum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ limsup_A(a_n) \leq sup_A(a_n)$$
$$ sup_A(a_n) \leq M $$
$$ limsup_A(a_n) = M $$
combining these leads to 
$$ M = limsup_A(a_n) \leq sup_A(a_n) \leq M$$

FYI: What you wrote is not what you meant.
Writing $$ \exists \{a_n\} \in A : limsup(a_n) = M$$ means that there exists a Set {a_n} within A. Thats not what you mean. You mean that there exists element a_n in A
$$ \exists a_n \in A$$
If you meant there exists a series , then you write 
$$ (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $$

and the existens Quantor is redundant in that case.